# Disable a row in gridview based on column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I am using the below code to disable row in gridview where the column name is test. Everything works fine except for the first row. The color does not get applied to the first row. Where am I going wrong?I also want to hide a column based on column name.

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (Hidden4.Value == "Data Present")
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow item in GdvTestData.Rows)
        {
            int a = GetColumnIndexByName(item, "test");
            int b = GetColumnIndexByName(item, "id");

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string test = e.Row.Cells[a].Text;

                foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
                {
                    if (test == "Y")
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "alert('This data is for testing');");
                    }
                }
                e.Row.Cells[b].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping the `GridViewRows` when you already have access to the current row (`e.Row`) in the `RowDataBound` event (which is executed for every row in the first place)?

Comment: how do I rewrite . if I don't use the loop then am not able to use  GetColumnIndexByName.

Comment: Looping is wrong. It means you are going to do it for every row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confusing data/business logic and UI.

RowDataBound event works per row so you don't need to loop gridview rows.

You are working on cell content but you have data bound to those. So:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" ...
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>              
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Test") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                ...
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void GrdBind()
{
    // populate datatable
    gv.DataSource = myDataTable;
    gv.Databind();
}
```

And the databound event:

```
    protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Hidden4.Value == "Data Present")
        { 
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
               DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
               string test = row.Field<String>("Test");

               if (test== "Y")
               {
                  e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Gray; // set your index
                  e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "alert('This data is for testing');");
               }
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: What is item.Test and what is foo for.I am also using  int a = GetColumnIndexByName(item, "test"); to get the index by referring to column name test.

Comment: I edited my previous post. What kind of data are you binding to GridView?

Comment: its datatable queried from sql

Comment: I edited it again. Try to check. This time i didn't test it.

Comment: its not just adding the backcolor. I also want to hide a column based on column name. On gridview load I need to hide the id column.

Comment: You won't hide a column because cell content is Y. You can have a cell with Y and another with N, so the column must be visible. Maybe do you mean cell and not column? Business logic to hide column must be set before Databind or in OnPreRender. I have seen you edit your question. Use a Label inside cell and hide the Label.

Comment: I need to hide the column. The functionality is to display all the columns (select *) except the column id. My code is working fine except that the first row is not getting affected

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Although I don't understand what you mean by disabling a row.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the dataitem back to a datarowview 
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //find the column value in the row, not the cell text
        string test = row["columnName"].ToString();

        //check the value and if so apply backcolor
        if (test == "Y")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;

            //or hide the row (no need to do this in Databind or OnPreRender)
            e.Row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```